# how to code view with a "submit" AND "delete" method

Tags: django, django-views

I have a simple app that takes entries/tasks and distibutes them to appropriate inbox's.
The model, template and view follows. What I want to do is modify the view so that I can
have a functional "delete" button in my form (alongside the "add/submit" button, like in an admin form.):

```
models.py

class InboxEntry(models.Model):
        job_number = models.CharField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\w{8}$', message='Please enter a valid job number', code='nomatch')], max_length=8, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
        cell_number = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
        job_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
        request = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=PRINT_CHOICES)
        date_in = models.DateField(("Date"), auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
        date_due = models.DateTimeField(("Due"),auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
        basecamp_link = models.URLField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^(http|https)://', message='url must begin with http or https', code='nomatch')], blank=True, null=False, max_length=300)
        note = models.TextField(max_length=1000, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
        assigned_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=False, null=False)
        box = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=INBOX_CHOICES)
        assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
        assigned_team = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectTeam, blank=True, null=True)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="Awaiting Action")
        accepted_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
        completed_on = models.DateTimeField(("Completed"),auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)

        def __unicode__ (self):
            return u'%s %s' % (self.job_number, self.job_name)

        class Admin: 
            pass



views.py

def edit_prdInboxEntry(request, id, userid):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a=InboxEntry.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = PrdInboxForm(request.POST, instance=a)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/production-display/'+ userid +'/')
    else:
        a=InboxEntry.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = PrdInboxForm(instance=a)
        user = request.user
        u = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=userid)
        creativerecords = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box="Creative")
        studiorecords = InboxEntry.objects.filter(box="Studio")
        records = InboxEntry.objects.filter(assigned_to=u)
        return render_to_response('production_InboxEntry.html', {'form': form, 'records': records, 'studiorecords': studiorecords, 'creativerecords': creativerecords, 'user': user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


template

<form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <div style="display:table;">
            <div style="display:table-row;">
                <div style="display:table-cell;">
                    <div class="group_input">
                    {{ form.assigned_by.errors }}
                    <label for="id_jassigned_by">Assigned by:</label>
                    {{ form.assigned_by }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">&nbsp; <div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">&nbsp; <div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">&nbsp; <div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">&nbsp; <div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">&nbsp; </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display:table-row;">
                <div style="display:table-cell;">
                    <div class="group_input">
                    {{ form.job_number.errors }}
                    <label for="id_job_number">job no:</label>
                    {{ form.job_number }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">
                    <div class="group_input">
                    {{ form.cell_number.errors }}
                    <label for="id_cell_number">cell:</label>
                    {{ form.cell_number }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">
                    <div class="group_input">
                        {{ form.job_name.errors }}
                        <label for="job_name">job name:</label>
                        {{ form.job_name }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">
                    <div class="group_input">
                        {{ form.request.errors }}
                        <label for="request">request:</label>
                        {{ form.request }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">
                    <div class="group_input">
                        {{ form.note.errors }}
                        <label for="id_note">note:</label>
                        {{ form.note }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">
                    <div class="container">
                          <!--  <div class='well'> -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                        <label for="id_date_due">date_due:</label>
                                        {{ form.date_due}}
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <!--    </div> -->
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function () {
                                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                                });
                            </script>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>  <!-- end css table-row -->
            <div style="display:table-row;">
                    <div style="display:table-cell;">
                        <div class="group_input">
                            {{ form.box.errors }}
                            <label for="id_box">inbox:</label>
                            {{ form.box }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:table-cell;">
                        <div class="group_input">
                            {{ form.assigned_to.errors }}
                            <label for="assigned_to">assigned_to:</label>
                            {{ form.assigned_to }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:table-cell;">
                        <div class="group_input">
                            {{ form.basecamp_link.errors }}
                            <label for="id_basecamp_link">basecamp:</label>
                            {{ form.basecamp_link }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:table-cell;">
                        <div class="accepted_by">
                            {{ form.accepted_by.errors }}
                            <label for="accepted_by">accepted_by:</label>
                            {{ form.accepted_by }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="display:table-cell;">
                        <div class="group_input">
                            {{ form.status.errors }}
                            <label for="id_status">status:</label>
                            {{ form.status }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:table-cell;">
                        <div class="container">
                              <!--  <div class='well'> -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                                            <label for="id_completed_on">completed:</label>
                                            {{ form.completed_on}}
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <!--    </div> -->
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
                                    });
                                </script>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>  <!-- end css table-row -->
            <div style="display:table-row;">
                <div style="display:table-cell;">&nbsp;</div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">
                    <p><input id="inbox_submit_btn" type="submit" value="add" /></p>
                </div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;">
                    <p><input id="inbox_delete_btn" type="submit" value="delete" /></p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>  <!-- end css table -->

</form>
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction. The docs seem to suggest that I need separate views and urls but I'm pretty sure this can be accomplished in a single view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The docs seem to suggest that I need separate views and urls but I'm pretty sure this can be accomplished in a single view?`

You could do this by passing in different POST parameters depending on which button was pressed, I guess. This is still quite a weird thing to want to do though. It's far neater and more maintainable to split them into different views.

You may be under a misapprehension when it comes to the views linking to templates. having two separate views (one for submissions, one for deletions) in no way affects your ability to display the  two buttons that link to those view urls in your template.

If you're worried about code reuse (function-based views often share a lot of code, so this is a reasonable complaint) then I suggest looking into [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/)

Edit:

It's just a case of linking to your second "delete" view with the button:

```
<div class="your-button-class" href="{% url "your-delete-view" pk=object.pk %}></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is it exactly. I have no problem writing a second view for deletions but I don't understand how to target the "delete view" with the "delete button" in the form.